# Overriding parent's attributes with child's class attributes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a scheme of cooperative classes based on `collection.abc`. When I subclass them, I want to be able to define just a couple of class attributes that then become the default values at instantiation, like so:

```
class MyFancyClass:
    # Defines various attributes, as class attributes and/or in the
    # __init__ method
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class A(myFancyClass):
    # Instances of A should have these values, even if they override
    # a value set in MyFancyClass's __init__ method:
    a = 2
    b = 2
    c = SomeHelperClass
```

Currently, in the `__init__` of `FancyClass`, I do:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for k, v in vars(type(self)).items():
        if k.startswith("_"):
            continue
        if k not in kwargs:
            kwargs[k] = v
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

That works fine, but if I make a class `B` that is a subclass of `A`, I lose those values defined for `A`, and I want to keep them.

So playing around, I got stuck here...

```
class InitExtras:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for cls in type(self).__mro__:
            if cls == InitExtras:
                break
            for k, v in vars(cls).items():
                if k.startswith("_") or callable(v):
                    continue
                if k not in kwargs:
                    print(f"adding\n{k=}\n{v=}\n")
                    kwargs[k] = v
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Base:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{args = }")
        print(f"{kwargs = }")

class A(Base):
    def fun1(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def fun2(self):
        pass

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
    
    def __init__(self, *args, b=23, b2=32, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.b = b
        self.b2 = b2

class C(InitExtras, B):
    b = 42

class D(C):
    b2 = 420

class T:
    pass

class E(C):
    b2 = T

    def fun3(self):
        pass
```

This seem to do most of what I want, except that `E().b2` is `32`, not `T`. And if I remove the `callable()` filter, other stuff can get mixed in too, like extra functionalities one might define later to personalize classes even further if needed (`fun3` in the example). I don't want to need to do a new `__init__` each time.

So my question is, how to accomplish that?

Comment: As an aside, your `property`s seem completely pointless. `b` and `b2` should just be normal attribuets, your getters and setters **don't do anything**

Comment: Anyway, I don't really understand the point of all this, class variables will act as "default" values of an instance variable of the same name doesn't exist and tries to be accessed via an instance.

Comment: that is just an example, I use the property to document the attribute, verify the correctness in the setter, or calculate the value of the attribute if its something that change over time, is all part of the api I'm making

Comment: Don't put pointless noise in your example. It is all well and good that you are doing something *else*, but in your example here, it is simply bad code. In any case, again, I am not entirely sure what the point of all of this is.

Comment: is illustrative of what I do, and it might be relevant to whatever solution comes around...

Comment: Can you explain what your use case is that makes normal class attributes not work? As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, they naturally serve as "defaults" unless and until the individual instance doesn't override them. Alternatively, you can define defaults in the initializer, and call `super().__init__()` in the inheriting class. It's hard to know what to suggest without knowing what about the usual methods isn't working for you.

Comment: the parent class provide meaningful default values and set them in their own init, like the B example, so is kind of pointless to make those class attribute in the new class, because when making a new instance it will set the parent default, I of course could make a new init for the new class and set the new default that way, but that is rather cumbersome, so I would prefer that the class detect by itself that I set some new default as a class attribute and use that instead

Comment: I notice that you skipped callables, but in your first example, one of the attributes points to a class. Classes are callable. Not sure if you want this process to apply to that or not.

Comment: @CrazyChucky no, I don't want to filter out callables assigned to those attributes, so in the example e=E() e.b2 should be T

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to distinguish between, for instance, `foo = a_callable_that_already_exists` and `def foo():` inside a class definition (all else equal). They're both class attributes.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I arrive at a solution, check it out. And your comments where helpful to get there, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it, I did by making a metaclass, and to distinguish between different class attributes I limit it to just properties

abc_recipes.py

```
from abc import ABCMeta, ABC, abstractmethod

class PropertyConfigMeta(ABCMeta):

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, /, **kwargs):
        #list the properties that the new class would inherit
        properties = {p for bcls in bases
                        for cls in bcls.__mro__
                        for p,v in vars(cls).items()
                      if isinstance(v,property)
                      }
        #proceed to extract the attributes that would
        #overwrite the properties inherited by non-property
        new_default={}
        new_namespace = {}
        for k,v in namespace.items():
            if k in properties:
                if isinstance(v,property):
                    new_namespace[k] = v
                else:
                    new_default[k] = v
            else:
                new_namespace[k] = v
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, new_namespace, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(cls,"_new_default"):
            cls._new_default = {**cls._new_default, **new_default}
        else:
            cls._new_default = new_default
        return cls


class PropertyConfig(metaclass=PropertyConfigMeta):
    """cooperative class that transform

       class A(SomeClass):
           a = 1
           b = 2

       into

       class A(SomeClass):
           def __init__(self, *arg, a = 1, b = 2, **karg):
               super().__init__(*arg, a = a, b = b, **karg)

       so long as a and b are defined as properties in SomeClass 
       (or somewhere in the inheritance chain)

       class SomeClass:

           @property
           def a(self):
               ...

           @property
           def b(self):
               ...

        Use as

        class A(PropertyConfig, SomeClass):
           a = 1
           b = 2
       """

    def __init__(self,*arg,**kwargs):
        for k,v in self._new_default.items():
            if k not in kwargs:
                kwargs[k]=v
        super().__init__(*arg,**kwargs)



class ConfigClass(ABC):
    """Cooperative class that offer a default __repr__ method
       based on the abstract property .config"""

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def config(self) -> dict:
        """configuration of this class"""
        return {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({', '.join( f'{k}={v!r}' for k,v in self.config.items() )})"
```

sample use

```
import abc_recipes

class Base:
    def __init__(self,*arg,**karg):
        if arg:
            print(f"{arg=}")
        if karg:
            print(f"{karg=}")

class A(Base):
    pass

class B(abc_recipes.ConfigClass,A):

    def __init__(self,*a, b=23, b2=32, **k):
        super().__init__(*a,**k)
        self.b  = b
        self.b2 = b2

    @property
    def b(self):
        "b attribute"
        #print("b getter")
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self,v):
        #print("b setter")
        self._b=v

    @property
    def b2(self):
        "b2 atrribute"
        #print("b2 getter")
        return self._b2

    @b2.setter
    def b2(self,v):
        #print("b2 setter")
        self._b2=v

    @property
    def config(self) -> dict:
        """configuration of this class"""
        res = super().config
        res.update(b=self.b, b2=self.b2)
        return res

    
class C(abc_recipes.PropertyConfig,B):
    b=42
    pass

class D(C):
    b2=420
    pass

class T:
    pass

class E(C):
    b2 = T
    pi  = 3.14

class F(E):

    @property
    def b2(self):
        #print("rewriten b2 getter")
        return "rewriten b2"

    @b2.setter
    def b2(self, value):
        #print("rewriten b2 setter")
        pass
```

test

```
>>> F()
F(b=42, b2='rewriten b2')
>>> E()
E(b=42, b2=<class '__main__.T'>)
>>> D()
D(b=42, b2=420)
>>> C()
C(b=42, b2=32)
>>> B()
B(b=23, b2=32)
>>> e=E()
>>> e.pi
3.14
>>> f=F()
>>> f.pi
3.14
>>>
```